# How to get fancybox working with html actionlink in mvc4 razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, fancybox-2

I am trying to show a fancybox modal popup when a dynamically created html actionlink is clicked from within a table.  I am using MVC4 with razor.  I have tried multiple things from reading posts on stackoverflow and other sites, but nothing is working.  I am fairly new to MVC4 and javascript/jquery.

The current error I am getting is: object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox' when loading the Search page.

**_Layout.cshtml page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @*<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />*@
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divForm").fancybox({
        'autoScale': false,
        'autoDimensions': true,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'showCloseButton': true,
        'type': 'ajax'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - PipelineRx</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

**Search Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Popup()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Index.cshtml**
Contains actionlinks in the rows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "searchForm", id = "searchForm" }))
{
<div>
    <table id="orderSheetList" class="table-standard">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Last Name<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'LastName','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'LastName','False');" />
                </th>
                <th>First Name<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'FirstName','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'FirstName','False');" />
                </th>
                <th>Received Date Time<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ReceivedDateTime','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ReceivedDateTime','False');" />
                </th>
                <th>Client Name<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ClientFullName','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ClientFullName','False');" />
                </th>
                <th>XML</th>
                <th>Transaction ID<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'TransactionID','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'TransactionID','False');" />
                </th>
                <th>ID<input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/up.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ID','True');" />
                    <input type="image" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/down.png")' onclick="_search(0,'ID','False');" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ( item in Model.Orders)
            {
            <tr class="clickable">
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.LastName)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.FirstName)</td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.DateTime)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.ClientFullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*@Html.Encode(item.XML)*@
                    @Html.ActionLink("XML", "Popup", "Search", null, new {Class = "fancybox"})
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.TransactionID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.ID)</td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
}
```

**Popup.cshtml**
A page for the fancybox which will be modified later.

```
<text>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.fancybox.open({ "content": "This is a popup" });
            });
        </script>
</text>

<div id="divForm"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the idea to show the XML from `item.XML` in the popup?

Comment: Yes, some xml data is stored in the model used by the page and I want to display that in the popup.  I haven't added the code for sending the xml data to the popup yet, as I wanted to get the popup working first.

Comment: Ok, so basically want you want to do then is user ajax to retrieve the XML when the user clicks the link and then display that returned XML in the fancybox.  I'll elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple issues I can see.

1. Your `Popup` action is tagged with `HttpPost` but links generate Get requests.
2. The way you have it set up now your action link will redirect the browser to `Search/Popup` which is a partial view.  Rending just a partial view means there will be no layout page and the layout page is where you are including the fancybox scripts.

What you want to do is use ajax to fetch the XML and then display it in the fancybox.

Add this to your **Index.cshtml** view:

```
<!-- add the ID to the URL -->
@Html.ActionLink("XML", "Popup", "Search", new { id = item.ID }, new {Class = "fancybox"})

<script type="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a.fancybox').click(function () {
            // not sure what the exact syntax is for setting the content
            // looking at the fancybox options you may be able to specify the ajax
            // options instead of setting the content manually, something like this
            // maybe:
            // ajax: { url: $(this).attr('href') },
            $.fancybox.open({ 
                'content': $('<div>').load($(this).attr('href')),
                'autoScale': false,
                'autoDimensions': true,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'hideOnContentClick': true,
                'showCloseButton': true
            });
            // to cancel the redirect from clicking the link
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change your **Popup** action to take the ID as a parameter and fetch the XML:

```
// not sure what the type of your ID is
public ActionResult Popup(int id)
{
    // add code here to fetch the XML for the ID

    return PartialView(/*pass the XML as to the view here*/);
}
```

Change your **Popup.cshtml** to this:

```
@model string // unless you want the XML to be some more complex type
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div id="divForm">@Model</div>
```

Also, you can get rid of the form surrounding the table (unless you are planning on posting something back later on).  You should also remove the script with the fancybox call that is on your layout page.

Comment: Thanks.  I have corrected those issues, however I am still getting the object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox' error.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and that is a simple way of sending the data to the popup view, but I still get the error:
"object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox'" when loading any page.  Due to this, the fancybox never opens and the link just displays the new page containing the xml data.

Comment: I did notice on your layout page that you are rendering jquery at the very bottom.  Try moving it to the top before the other scripts that rely on it.

Comment: If I move those two lines of code, anywhere else, or even comment them out, then the error goes away when I navigate to any other page in my site using the layout, but on the Search page it is in an infinite refresh loop.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, that was an un-related issue that I resolved.  Once I moved the script rendering to the top it worked as expected.  I also removed the fancybox javascript from the layout page as I only needed in the search page.  Thanks!